# Failed to connect with REST web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have one web service in jersey that deploy on appache server, and I'm trying to connect that server but I get the following error :

```
Failed to load http://192.168.1.200:8199/CheckinnWeb/webapi/myresource/query: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

my service.ts file code is below

```js
 getlogin(): Observable<ILogin[]> {   
   return this._http
              .get(this._loginurl, this.headers)
              .map((response: Response) => <ILogin[]> response.json())
              .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

this is my server url

```
_loginurl='http://192.168.1.200:8199/CheckinnWeb/webapi/myresource/'+this.encodedString;
```

please help me to solve this..thank you!!

Comment: what is `this.encodedString`? looks like a sql query to me

Comment: looks like  a CORS issue to me . Have you tried adding` Access-Control-Allow-Origin` request header to your `this.headers` ?check whether the apache hosted service allows cross domain requests or not

Comment: This is not a clear question! You should supply more details. 
as I see this is your endpoint "...webapi/myresource"
and this is your parameter "select ...." am I right? if this is not a parameter, then use ? querystring!
The problem is on your endpoint,
Can you debug your endpoint?
What does your service URL respond?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 getlogin(): Promise<ILogin[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._loginurl)
        .toPromise().then(response => <ILogin[]>response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is not an error with `angular2` itself. But it's more to do with your `CORS` configuration on server side.

You have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your response from your service. You can set something like below which says you basically allow any resource:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import {Headers} from "@angular/http";

let headers=new Headers({ 
    });
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

  getlogin(): Promise<ILogin[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._loginurl,{headers:headers}))
        .toPromise().then(response => <ILogin[]>response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```